# How to make SOAP calls in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, soap

I am trying to make soap call to get data from 3rd party website. How can i use soap api call in magento2 ?

Answer (score 12):

Inject `\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory` in the class where you need it:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory $soapClientFactory)
{
    $this->soapClientFactory = $soapClientFactory;
}
```

Then use it to instantiate a [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/SoapClient) instance:

```
$soapClient = $this->soapClientFactory->create($wsdl, $options);
```

For the parameters `$wsdl` and `$options` as well as usage examples, please refer to the PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: hi Fabian, i tried the code and then discovered, a missing "create" should you now "create it", like  

       $soapClient =    $this->soapClientFactory->create(
            $wsdl,
            $options
        );

Answer (score 0):

You can use zend soap like this.

```
$api = new \Zend\Soap\Client(NULL, $options);
```